# NetBeans 8 PHPUnit

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I have installed PHPUnit follows to their website instructions.
When I'm trying to generate test class
I got this message:

> "D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\phpunit-skelgen.bat" "--ansi"
> "generate-test" "main" "D:\Projects\tdd\main.php" "mainTest"
> "D:\Projects\tdd\tests\mainTest.php"
>
> The referenced parameter '--ansi' is not registered.
>
> Done.

This is happening in Windows and Linux environment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened the same to me. It seems that we were using the old phpunit-skelgen 1.2.1 version. Apparently, NetBeans 8.0.1 assumes you are using the newest version of phpunit-skelgen, that is 2.0.1.

download the new skelgen phar and update the batch file (windows) and you are good to go .

for visual guide follow these blog. 
http://kevindaus.blogspot.com/2015/01/fix-netbeans-8-create-test-problem.html

Answer (score 1):

You can [install it via composer globally](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer) which will also currently give you [v2.0.1](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator):

`composer global require "phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator=*"`

Then put `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpunit-skelgen.bat` into Netbeans Tools > Options > PHP (tab) > Frameworks & Tools (tab) > PHPUnit section.